# My question is about CSS universal selector

Tags: css

I'm actually trying to building a website, but the universal selector doesn't work. I tried many times, and yet it does not work. Here's an example of what I'm doing: https://codepen.io/Razu381/pen/XQJVzg.

I used this for my CSS:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in your `CSS` is invalid and breaking future rules. Remove it or fix it and your `CSS` will work as expected.

```css
#e67e22;=orange;
```

If you meant to create a native `CSS Variable` (aka, [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)), you could replace the above with this:

```css
:root {
  --orange: #e67e22;
}
```

It could be used like this:

```css
.btn-full{
  background-color: var(--orange);
  border: 1px solid var(--orange);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you mr. andy.it solved.I was so tensed about that,thank you so much.

Comment: @Razu If you’re happy with my answer, I’d be grateful if you could select it as the chosen answer.

Comment: sir,i don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Razu There is a checkmark beneath my answer that you can click (as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/dV7KSKb)).